# How did they create this fancy diagram?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, diagram

I found a fancy diagram (with animation) [NYTimes Fancy Diagram](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/10/15/us/politics/swing-history.html) on a NYTimes webpage.
Does anybody know about such diagram, the underlying techs and possible tools please? I really want to know how to generate such diagram. 
I suppose HTML5 or javascript did the great job. But I don't know much about those techs...
Thanks very much for your attention!!!

Comment: Welcome to [so]; please review the [faq].

Comment: It's SVG and probably some Javascript to handle the hover effect.

Comment: Looks like they used http://d3js.org/

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments. Also, I should have read the faq carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[d3js.org](http://d3js.org/) is a very flexible and powerful framework for diagrams like that (incl. animations).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my very first question here. It did answer my question. I will also try to ask better questions next time.